# How to detect child div's height exceeding parent div's height

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div A, which contains div B, which contains div C, which contains div D, where div A has a **default** height of 40px. It's something like below.

```
<div id='A' style="height: 40px">
  <div id='B'>
     <div id='C'>
         <div id='D'></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The thing is, div C is implemented in a way that it can dynamically change height. Therefore, it could exceed the default height of div A (40px) and cause some cosmetic issue.

What I want to achieve is to keep the height of div A as 40px as long as the height of any its child div doesn't exceed 40px. However, if the height of any its child div exceeds 40px, I want height of the child div to **override** div A's height. For example, when div C changes height to 80px, I want div A's height to be 80px.

I am wondering if I need to write a method to dynamically calculate the height of each child div and do something like `getElementById('A').style.height = null` if the child height returned is greater than 40px.

Is there a better or simpler way to do that?

Comment: So, [min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using 'min-height'.

```
 min-height: 40px;
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the my point you no need to check each child element height.

If you check B child element height is more than enough, because that is the parent for child element C and D

According to that, following JS code will provide you the solution

```
// get parent div #A 
var parentElement = document.getElementById('A'); 

// parent div #A initialHeight
var parentDivOffsetHeight = 40; // no need to mentionion px

// get child div #B offest height
var childDivOffsetHeight = document.getElementById('B').offsetHeight;

// check if child div height is greater than parent div or not
if(childDivOffsetHeight > parentDivOffsetHeight){
    //set child div height to parent div
    parentElement.style.height = childDivOffsetHeight+'px';
}
```

Related JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/katheer_mizal/3ouypevd/18/

To check element hights you can use following ways

**clientHeight** includes padding.

```
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('B').clientHeight;
```

**offsetHeight** includes padding, scrollBar and borders.

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('B').offsetHeight;
```

**.style.height** equalent to $('#content').css('height'.

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('B').style.height;
```

Comment: If you no need to overide default inline height of element #A, you can use #A {min-height: 40px; height: auto; } and remove inline style from element #A